# Faster way to eliminate duplicates from list

Tags: python, list, optimization, duplicates

I use an API to download ticket numbers from a website and then I count the unique ticket IDs in the arrays that I create that only accept one instance of an ID.

This is very slow... I have tried using sets, and it is worse. I have seen mention of other tools, such as itertools but no clear explanation on how I could use it in a situation similar to mine.

The good and bad variables store a type of Generator from what I can tell. Thanks so much for your help!!!

```
    good = self._client.satisfaction_ratings(score="good",sort_order="asc",start_time=thirty_days,end_time=today)
    bad = self._client.satisfaction_ratings(score="bad", sort_order="asc", start_time=thirty_days, end_time=today)
    good_array = []
    bad_array = []
    for g in good:
        if g.ticket.id not in good_array:
            good_array.append(g.ticket.id)
    for b in bad:
        if b.ticket.id not in bad_array:
            bad_array.append(b.ticket.id)
    goodnum = len(good_array)
    badnum = len(bad_array)
```

Comment: have you tried set comprehension? `good_array = {g.ticket.id for g in good}`. That cannot be slow.

Comment: That would work for eliminating duplicates? Do I add an if statement to it like this: {g.ticket.id for g in good if g not in ????} The fact that I have to check the list to see if the value already exists is what is killing the speed I think.

Comment: yes, sets eliminate duplicates, updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if g.ticket.id not in good_array` with `good_array` as a `list` is slow all right since it uses linear search (and I understand the order doesn't matter)

Using `set` is the perfect way to keep only unique elements (and that *cannot* be slower, you must have used them in a wrong way)

Now, just drop the loops and create 2 set comprehensions:

```
good_array = {g.ticket.id for g in good}
bad_array = {g.ticket.id for g in bad}
```

then count as you did:

```
goodnum = len(good_array)
badnum = len(bad_array)
```

Comment: The time difference was still quite minimal but it was a few seconds faster. On average maybe 55 seconds instead of 59. This helped me understand sets better though, so thank you for that.

Comment: on a greater data set the time difference it more noticeable.

Answer (score -1):

set is a python datatype which doesn't allow duplicates.
simply cast your good and bad lists to set -

```
unique_good = set(good)
unique_bad = set(bad)
```

You can get length of the set in the same way you got for list.

Comment: This is not equivalent because here you create sets from the items in `good` and `bad` instead of the ids, as in `g.ticket.id`. That's why the list comprehension is needed, as can be seen in the already existing answer. Also you are not casting to set, you are creating new sets using the `set()` function.